# Mapbox marker popups wont open/close individually

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mapbox, mapbox-gl, mapbox-marker

When a user added marker is clicked on my map it opens up popups for all the markers on the map[image]

The popups open up for the individual marker that is clicked on database loaded markers but for 'setShowUserPopup' they open for every single marker a user has added as shown in the photo (the forms are the popup content)

Thanks for any help in advance!

```js
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import ReactMapGL, { Marker, Popup } from "react-map-gl";

import { listLogEntries } from "./API";
import LogEntryForm from "./LogEntryForm";
import { Grid, Card, Icon, Fab } from "@material-ui/core";

const BasicMap = () => {
  // Markers loaded from database
  const [logEntries, setLogEntries] = useState([]);
  const [showPopup, setShowPopup] = useState({});

  // Markers from user input
  const [userMarkers, setUserMarkers] = useState([]);
  const [showUserPopup, setShowUserPopup] = useState({});

  // viewport is all the infomation about the default map state
  const [viewport, setViewport] = useState({
    width: "100vw",
    height: "100vh",
    latitude: 52.950001,
    longitude: -1.15,
    zoom: 6,
    minZoom: 3
    // maxZoom: 3
  });

  // Get entries from API

  const getEntries = async () => {
    const logEntries = await listLogEntries();
    setLogEntries(logEntries);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    getEntries();
  }, []);

  const showAddMarkerPopup = event => {
    const [longitude, latitude] = event.lngLat;

    setUserMarkers([
      ...userMarkers,
      {
        id: userMarkers.length + 1,
        lat: latitude,
        long: longitude,
        draggable: true
      }
    ]);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("userMarkers", userMarkers);
  }, [userMarkers]);

  return (
    <ReactMapGL
      {...viewport}
      mapStyle="mapbox://styles/veleter/ck7xdy1yo1bkj1ipmsbhe9c96"
      mapboxApiAccessToken={process.env.REACT_APP_MAPBOX_TOKEN}
      onViewportChange={setViewport}
      onClick={showAddMarkerPopup}
    >
      {/* DATABASE LOADED MARKERS */}
      {logEntries.map(entry => (
        <React.Fragment key={entry._id}>
          <Marker latitude={entry.latitude} longitude={entry.longitude}>
            <div
              onClick={() =>
                setShowPopup({
                  ...showPopup,
                  [entry._id]: true
                })
              }
            >
              <svg
                className="marker yellow"
                style={{
                  height: `${6 * viewport.zoom}px`,
                  width: `${6 * viewport.zoom}px`
                }}
                version="1.1"
                id="Layer_1"
                x="0px"
                y="0px"
                viewBox="0 0 512 512"
              >
                <g>
                  <g>
                    <path
                      d="M256,0C153.755,0,70.573,83.182,70.573,185.426c0,126.888,165.939,313.167,173.004,321.035
                        c6.636,7.391,18.222,7.378,24.846,0c7.065-7.868,173.004-194.147,173.004-321.035C441.425,83.182,358.244,0,256,0z M256,278.719
                        c-51.442,0-93.292-41.851-93.292-93.293S204.559,92.134,256,92.134s93.291,41.851,93.291,93.293S307.441,278.719,256,278.719z"
                    />
                  </g>
                </g>
              </svg>
            </div>
          </Marker>
          {showPopup[entry._id] ? (
            <Popup
              latitude={entry.latitude}
              longitude={entry.longitude}
              closeButton={true}
              closeOnClick={false}
              dynamicPosition={true}
              onClose={() =>
                setShowPopup({
                  ...showPopup,
                  [entry._id]: false
                })
              }
              anchor="top"
            >
              <div className="popup">
                {/* <h3>{entry.title}</h3>
                <p>{entry.comments}</p>
                <p>
                  <b>Longitude: </b>
                  {entry.longitude}
                </p>
                <p>
                  <b>Latitude: </b>
                  {entry.latitude}
                </p>
                <small>
                  Ticket Placed:{" "}
                  {new Date(entry.visitDate).toLocaleDateString()}
                </small>
                {entry.image && <img src={entry.image} alt={entry.title} />} */}

                <Card elevation={3} className="p-4">
                  <div className="flex items-center">
                    <Fab
                      size="medium"
                      className="bg-light-error circle-44 box-shadow-none overflow-hidden"
                    >
                      <Icon className="text-error">star_outline</Icon>
                    </Fab>
                    <h5 className="font-medium text-error m-0 ml-3">
                      {entry.title}
                    </h5>
                  </div>
                  <div className="pt-4 flex items-center">
                    <h2 className="m-0 text-muted flex-grow"></h2>
                    <div className="ml-3 small-circle bg-error text-white"></div>
                    <span className="text-13">({entry.longitude})</span>
                    <span className="text-13">({entry.latitude})</span>
                  </div>
                </Card>
              </div>
            </Popup>
          ) : null}
        </React.Fragment>
      ))}

      {/* USER ADDED MARKER */}

      {userMarkers.map(userMarker => (
        <React.Fragment key={userMarker._id}>
          <Marker
            latitude={userMarker.lat}
            longitude={userMarker.long}
            draggable
            // onDragEnd={setUserMarkers}
          >
            <div
              onClick={() =>
                setShowUserPopup({
                  ...showUserPopup,
                  [userMarker._id]: true
                })
              }
            >
              <div>
                <svg
                  className="marker red"
                  style={{
                    height: `${6 * viewport.zoom}px`,
                    width: `${6 * viewport.zoom}px`
                  }}
                  version="1.1"
                  id="Layer_1"
                  x="0px"
                  y="0px"
                  viewBox="0 0 512 512"
                >
                  <g>
                    <g>
                      <path
                        d="M256,0C153.755,0,70.573,83.182,70.573,185.426c0,126.888,165.939,313.167,173.004,321.035
                        c6.636,7.391,18.222,7.378,24.846,0c7.065-7.868,173.004-194.147,173.004-321.035C441.425,83.182,358.244,0,256,0z M256,278.719
                        c-51.442,0-93.292-41.851-93.292-93.293S204.559,92.134,256,92.134s93.291,41.851,93.291,93.293S307.441,278.719,256,278.719z"
                      />
                    </g>
                  </g>
                </svg>
              </div>
            </div>
          </Marker>

          {showUserPopup[userMarker._id] ? (
            <Popup
              latitude={userMarker.lat}
              longitude={userMarker.long}
              closeButton={true}
              closeOnClick={false}
              dynamicPosition={true}
              onClose={() =>
                setShowUserPopup({
                  ...showUserPopup,
                  [userMarker._id]: false
                })
              }
              anchor="top"
            >
              <div className="popup">
                <LogEntryForm />
              </div>
            </Popup>
          ) : null}
        </React.Fragment>
      ))}
    </ReactMapGL>
  );
};
export default BasicMap;
```

Answer (score 1):

The error comes from not passing an exact id to the market. When you click on a marker and set it to `true`, you do so for all markers on the map.

What you need to do is pass an ID to the element you need to open, that being the modal and then target the ID with your `onClick` event.

```
 onClick={e => {
      setShowPopup(e.currentTarget.id);
}}
```

Then to display the element that you want, you should compare the value from the `event` to the ID:

```
{userMarkersID === showUserPopup.id && (
      <div>Whatever you wanna show</div>
)}
```

Where `userMarkersID` is the ID for each marker that you have on the map. Hope that helps